# C# WPF XAML status bar alignment

Tags: c#, wpf, alignment, statusbar, status

Everything is fine when the text is default on startup [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl5Bg.png), but when I add song name, status is moving to right and status bar are outside area. [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJFDQ.png)

```
<StatusBar Margin="0,730,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
        <WrapPanel >
        <Label x:Name="tytulUtworu" HorizontalAlignment="Left">music: none </Label>
        <Label x:Name="lblstatusPolaczenia" Margin="200,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">status: disconnected</Label>
        <ProgressBar Width="100" Height="15" Value="50" Margin="200,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </StatusBar>
```

How can I repair this?

Comment: Why do you have such a large margin defined when you have the panel docked to the bottom of the window? Surely the docking is enough that you don't need a 730 pixel margin to the top?

Comment: Without Margin dockpanel isn't docked to the bottom, idk why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, ditch the margins.
They are not helping, they just make things less obvious as to how they should be aligned.

From your margin values, I'm guessing that you want the status bar to show the label on the left, another in the center, and the progress bar on the right.

Below shows how to do this with a second dock panel. 
Dock panel is ideal here as it is consistent in the way it reports its size to child components.

If you want to place this status panel on another `DockPanel`, there are a few things which must be done before it will render as you need it to.

Firstly, you main dock panel must have content, otherwise the boundary panels will not render in the right place.

Secondly, if you have set `LastChildFill=True`, you must add your main content as the last item.
If you set the main content then add your status bar, even though you have docked it to the bottom, it will still try to fill the panel.

I've updated the code snippet after testing it (my first attempt was typed straight into SO, sorry it didn't work).

```
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
               Name="statusBar"
               Height="50"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True"
                   Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=statusBar, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ProgressBar DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                         Width="100"
                         Value="50" />
            <Label x:Name="tytulUtworu"
                   DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                   ContentStringFormat="music: {0}"
                   Content="none" />
            <Label x:Name="lblstatusPolaczenia" 
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                   Content="disconnected"
                   ContentStringFormat="status: {0}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </StatusBar>
```

Comment: Try that snippet now.

Comment: With long song title it's moving center status to the right ;) but progressBar is fine. I'm very curious what does the code Width.... mode=OneWay" do(?) https://ibb.co/drJ4Ua

Comment: @Sheep it binds the width of the dock panel to the width of the status bar. The binding is on the property `ActualWidth` of the status bar, and the `OneWay` means that changes to the size of the status bar will change the dock panel on it. Some WPF components don't always behave as you would expect when resizing. This approach ensures that the sizes update properly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `WrapPanel`, try using a `Grid`. That way you'll have fixed columns that won't affect the other elements if text is added

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="tytulUtworu" HorizontalAlignment="Left">music: none </Label>
    <Label x:Name="lblstatusPolaczenia" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">status: disconnected</Label>
    <ProgressBar Width="100" Height="15" Value="50" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>
```

You can adjust the `Width` on each ColumnDefinition to get better sized columns for your use